# How to create firebug like extension using addon sdk

Tags: jquery, angularjs, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to create an Firefox extension; like an firebug, which will act as logger for some custom Javascript framework.

I have created the same for `Chrome`, as a part of devtools, and now trying to port the same for Firefox. Unfortunately, I haven't find any help for the same on net as well as over mozilla's documentation. Below I list the issues which I am facing,

- Create a firebug like interface
- Use jQuery, Bootstrap and Angular within extension

Just for the reference, I am using `addon-sdk-1.16` from mozilla to create this extension.

Any help over the issues will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/firebug/firebug

Comment: It's pretty complex man. But if you want to start inspecting css stuff use [`inIDOMUtils`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/inIDOMUtils) I'm not sure how to do js logging. But an interface like firebug, i think they use a lot of xul, you might just want to create a sidebar and then load an iframe with your gui in it. Here's how to make a sidebar: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/8728393

Comment: Isn't there a smart and simple way to do it? Just like an chrome dev-tool extension?
Thanks though will look into your refrences

Comment: On the [MDN :: XPCOM Interface Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface) page check out `nsIEventListenerService`, `nsIEventListenerInfo` they have some stuff i think you would like.

Comment: Do you have your chrome extension for demo? I'm in need of developing an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the native devtools have a [basic api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DevToolsAPI) for adding a new tool to the toolbox. It works but it is a bit awkward. For examples of how this works with a reasonably complex add-on, see these:

- [Ember Inspector](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector)
- [Angular Batarang](https://github.com/rpl/angularjs-batarang)

These are ports of the related chrome extensions by Luca Greco, who also created a [nice grunt plugin](https://github.com/rpl/grunt-mozilla-addon-sdk).

In the near future the add-on SDK will have a new, more powerful set of apis:

https://github.com/Gozala/addon-sdk/blob/jeps/devtools/Developer%20pane.md

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. Will check and revert back accordingly.